# Terraform : How to update hashicorp/google-beta v3.90.1 to v4.0.0

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I cannot explain why when i run `terraform init -upgrade` the provider google v3.90.1 is always here.

Look at my backend file which not specify none provider

```
terraform {
}
```

I have this specification

```
provider "google" {
  project = var.project
  region  = var.region
  
  scopes = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
  ]
}
```

Or something like that further in modules

```
module "scc-build-docker" {
  source          = "terraform-google-modules/project-factory/google"
  version         = "~> 10.1"
  (...)
}

> gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 404.0.0
alpha 2022.09.23
beta 2022.09.23

> terrafom -v
terraform v0.14.11
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/archive v2.2.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google v3.90.1
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google-beta v3.90.1
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null v3.1.1
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v3.4.3
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template v2.2.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/time v0.8.0
```

How could i upgrade google provider to the last one ?

Thanks.

After specify inside versions.tf

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 0.14.0"
  
  required_providers {
    google   = "= 4.38.0"
    google-beta = "= 4.38.0"
  }  
}
```

Issue is still exist

```
Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/null versions matching ">= 2.1.0"...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/time...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/archive...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/template...
- Finding hashicorp/google versions matching ">= 2.12.0, >= 3.43.0, ~> 3.45, >= 3.50.0, >= 3.53.0, ~> 3.53, < 4.0.0, 4.38.0, < 5.0.0"...
- Finding hashicorp/google-beta versions matching ">= 3.1.0, >= 3.43.0, ~> 3.45, >= 3.50.0, < 4.0.0, 4.38.0, < 5.0.0"...
- Finding hashicorp/random versions matching ">= 2.2.0"...
- Installing hashicorp/null v3.1.1...
- Installed hashicorp/null v3.1.1 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/time v0.8.0...
- Installed hashicorp/time v0.8.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/archive v2.2.0...
- Installed hashicorp/archive v2.2.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/template v2.2.0...
- Installed hashicorp/template v2.2.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/random v3.4.3...
- Installed hashicorp/random v3.4.3 (signed by HashiCorp)

Error: Failed to query available provider packages

Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
hashicorp/google: no available releases match the given constraints >= 2.12.0,
>= 3.43.0, ~> 3.45, >= 3.50.0, >= 3.53.0, ~> 3.53, < 4.0.0, 4.38.0, < 5.0.0


Error: Failed to query available provider packages

Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
hashicorp/google-beta: no available releases match the given constraints >=
3.1.0, >= 3.43.0, ~> 3.45, >= 3.50.0, < 4.0.0, 4.38.0, < 5.0.0
```

As I removed main.tf file, all seems working fine. Then I try to activate/disable block to see which one triggers this issue.
So, in face, this block is the reason why plugin provider cannot be installed

```
module "shared" {
  providers = {
    google      = google.impersonated
    google-beta = google-beta.impersonated
  }
  source = "./modules/shared"

  depends_on = [module.projects]

  # Read created projects. Produced map : key is environment key, value is project resource
  target_projects = { for k, v in local.projects : k => merge(v, module.projects[k].project) }

  docker_repositories = local.docker_repositories

  terraform_sa_email = data.google_service_account.terraform_sa.email

  region                     = var.region
  organization_id            = data.google_project.factory_project.org_id
  billing_account            = var.billing_account
  parent_folder              = module.folders.shared_folder.id
  team                       = "scc"
  creator                    = data.google_service_account.terraform_sa.account_id
  controlling_group_name     = local.controlling_group_name
  controlling_group_fullname = local.controlling_group_fullname
}
```

...

Ok resolved... I have to set all latest version for modules..
(as terraform-google-modules/network/google for examples)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a `versions.tf` file to declare your providers with versions and upgrade them when it's needed.

Example of `versions.tf` file with `Google` and `Google beta` providers and `4.38.0` version :

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13.2"

  required_providers {
    google   = "= 4.38.0"
    google-beta = "= 4.38.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mazulum, could you see my update ? please. My issue is still here :(

Comment: If you only launch `terraform init`instead of `terraform init -upgrade`, which is the behaviour ?

Comment: Yes, I have the same trace :  Error: Failed to query available provider packages

Comment: Can you remove your specification and test without it ? : 
`provider "google" {
  project = var.project
  region  = var.region
  
  scopes = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
  ]
}
`

Comment: Yes I removes these blocks. No effect. Same trace error. But if I rename this main.tf file.. It Works

Comment: See my last update. Try to specify versions in module shared... but without success